# string match timestamp to long in scala

Tags: scala, match

I have a string, it could be:

1. "unknown"
2. digital string of timestamp like `"1487905455000"`
3. formatted date string like `"Tue Feb 14 11:27:07 +0800 2017"`

I want to transfer that to unix timestamp as `Long` according to each case:

1. "unknown" will be transferred to `-1`
2. string of time stamp will be transferred to the long value `1487905455000L`
3. formatted date string will be parsed to timestamp

so Here is what I think about to do this:

```
createTimeStamp = {
    createTimestamp match {
       case "unknown" => -1L
       case isDAlldigitas(x) => x.toLong
       caes _ => {
          val format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy")
          Try(format.parse(_).getTime) match {
             case Success(t) => t
             case Failure(_) => -1L
          }
       }
    }
}
```

Above code is not working, But I don't know which I have done it wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below works for three conditions. importantly for the third case replace `case _` with valid variable identifier such as `case x`

```
 def createTimeStamp(timeStamp: String) = {
   timeStamp match {
     case "unknown" => -1L
     case x if x.replaceAll("\\d", "") == "" => x.toLong
     case x =>  
          val format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy")
          Try(format.parse(x).getTime) match {
              case Success(t) => t
              case Failure(_) => -1L
          }
       }
     }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but what if format.parse(x) yield a exception?

Comment: @armnotstrong I assumed we always get the data in right format. Now I have updated the answer

Comment: thanks rogue, I  found the match case for scala is hard to understand and to make the best practice. Thanks again, I'll try this

Comment: @armnotstrong your welcome.. it will soon all makes sense.. once you get the hang of it.. :)